# Plot correlation between variables separated by two groups with facets in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to plot correlation pairs (Eye1,Hand1,Eye2,Hand2,Eye3,Hand3) and facet/ separate by groups and (1 and 2) and workspace. In the plot below, I want 3 correlation lines (each representing a workspace).[image]

```
data10 <- structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Workspace = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
    Eye1 = c(4, 8, 5, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 6, 4, 8, 4, 7, 
    5, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5), Hand1 = c(5, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 7, 
    7, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5), Eye2 = c(3, 
    7, 7, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 4, 
    3, 3, 4, 6), Hand2 = c(4, 6, 7, 4, 3, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 
    7, 4, 4, 7, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 7, 5, 5), Eye3 = c(4, 4, 5, 4, 
    5, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 7, 4, 6, 5, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 
    5), Hand3 = c(5, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 
    4, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Workspace = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Eye1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Hand1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Eye2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Hand2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Eye3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Hand3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
dataLong <- data10 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Group,
                                   names_to=c(".value","Index"),
                                   names_pattern = "(Eye|Hand)(\\d)") %>% 
  mutate(Group=paste0("Grp_",Group))

Cors <- dataLong %>% group_by(Group,Index) %>% summarize(Cor=round(cor(Eye,Hand),3))

ggplot(dataLong,aes(x=Hand,y=Eye))+geom_point()+
  facet_grid(Index~Group)+
  geom_text(aes(x=4,y=4,label=paste("r=",Cor)),data=Cors)
```

Comment: `data10` has pointers to objects in your memory, like e.g. connection objects. Did you `collect` it into a `data.frame` first?

Comment: shouldn't `cols` in `pivot_longer` be `-c(Group, Workspace)`?

Comment: If I copy the `data10`, the code fails.

Comment: Ihave updated it, it has something to do with the dput function

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very messy.

My first thought was to use `geom_smooth()` but it is quite hard to tell it what you want to pool together and what not. Basically, my idea is to compute the linear model to get the intercept and slope first, and then plot them with `geom_abline()` by specifying the group (`Index` in this example).

First, extract estimates from `lm()` for each group.

```
est <- by(dataLong, dataLong$Index, FUN = function(x) (lm(Eye~Hand, data=x)))
est <- sapply(est, coef)
```

Second, create a data set for convenience containing these estimate and their group.

```
estimate <- data.frame(Index = 1:3,
                  intercept = est[1,],
                  slope = est[2,])
```

Use the new data frame in `geom_abline(data = estimate, aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, group = Index))` and specify the intercept, slope and their group.

```
ggplot(dataLong,aes(x=Hand,y=Eye))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(data = estimate, aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, group = Index)) +
  facet_grid(Index~Group)+
  geom_text(aes(x=4,y=4,label=paste("r=",Cor)),data=Cors)
```

[image]